Object is not abstract and does not implement abstract member public abstract fun onMenuItemActionExpand
I am receiving these errors when building an APK, I have not changed anything except updating my IDE.

Object is not abstract and does not implement abstract member public abstract fun onMenuItemActionExpand(p0: MenuItem): Boolean defined in android.view.MenuItem.OnActionExpandListener

The second error: onMenuItemActionExpand overrides nothing
The third error:  onMenuItemActionCollapse overrides nothing
Code sample
menuItem.setOnActionExpandListener(object: MenuItem.OnActionExpandListener{

    override fun onMenuItemActionExpand(item: MenuItem?): Boolean {
        parentLayout.visibility = View.GONE
        rv_listX.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        return true
    }

    override fun onMenuItemActionCollapse(item: MenuItem?): Boolean {
        parentLayout.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        emptyX.visibility = View.GONE
        rv_listX.visibility = View.GONE
        return true
    }

})


If your original compileSDK was 32 or below and you upgrade compile SDK 33 or above, method parameter inside MenuItem.OnActionExpandListener interface changes from nullable to @NonNull.
MenuItem.OnActionExpandListener from SDK 32
public interface OnActionExpandListener {
    public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem item); 
    public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem item);
}

MenuItem.OnActionExpandListener from SDK 33
public interface OnActionExpandListener {
    public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(@NonNull MenuItem item); 
    public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(@NonNull MenuItem item);
}

Google added @NonNull to support Kotlin's Null safety.
Since the method signature changes, methods in your code override nothing.
Solution
Just remove null operator ? from both MenuItem.
menuItem.setOnActionExpandListener(object : MenuItem.OnActionExpandListener {
    override fun onMenuItemActionExpand(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
          parentLayout.visibility = View.GONE
          rv_listX.visibility = View.VISIBLE
          return true
    }

    override fun onMenuItemActionCollapse(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
          parentLayout.visibility = View.VISIBLE
          emptyX.visibility = View.GONE
          rv_listX.visibility = View.GONE
          return true
    }
})


worked like a charm thank you..I have been struggling for two days

@ Kaung Khant Kyaw While this answers the question you don't explain what the problem is and why your answer fixes it. Please consider editing it to help future users understand and learn

Anyone who wants to know how this fixes the problem is because the code written by the OP has methods with a different signature (parameters with different types(nullable)) than the original methods in the MenuItem.OnActionExpandListener interface so OP's methods override nothing.
